# Connecting VB Script and SQL Plus , passing value to Query

Tags: sql, scripting, vbscript, sqlplus

After reading from a text file , I am trying to connect to SQLplus with a value stored in a variable and trying to update a table but I am getting below error : " Unterminated String constant
Here is what code looks like, thanks to Guido for helping me out on Step 1.
Can anyone please point out the error . Some error inside If & Else Part , the SQL query or connection is wrong

```
dim fs, txt, line, yesno , cust_id
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set txt = fs.OpenTextFile("E:\batchfiletest\Eapp3\scotia1.txt", 1, false) 

' loop through all the lines
do while not txt.AtEndOfStream
    line = txt.readLine

' read the character and store it in a variable
    yesno = Mid(line, 127, 1)
    cust_id = Mid(line, 1,20)   

' execute the correct query
    if yesno = "Y" then

    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set oEnv=WshShell.Environment("Process") 
    cmdString = "E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\sqlplusw.exe -S sysman/csaadmin@convcsd

    UPDATE csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote set HOLD_CODE = 'CAQ' where quote_id =  cust_id ;
    commit;"

    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(cmdString)

     ELSE  
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set oEnv=WshShell.Environment("Process") 
    cmdString = "E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\sqlplusw.exe -S sysman/csaadmin@convcsd

    UPDATE csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote set HOLD_CODE = 'PVQ' where quote_id =  cust_id ;
    commit;"

    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(cmdString)

    end if
loop
MsgBox "Press OK to close when done reading the output."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the normal faster and safer way to do this is like

```
Const sConnectionStringOracle =  "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=xxxx.xxxxx;User id=xxx;password=xxx"
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.open sConnectionStringOracle
sql = "UPDATE csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote set HOLD_CODE = 'CAQ' where quote_id = " & cust_id
oConn.execute(sql)
'rest of the database transactions
oConn.close
Set oConn = nothing
```

You can add error trapping, logging etc.
Just make sure you have the Oracle OleDb driver installed on the pc you use this.
If you need to use Sql*Plus then write all the transactions to one sql textfile and have that run just once. You can then execute and debug the sql in case of errors.

Grtz

Comment: Are there any alternatives to fetch or update data without the Oracle OleDb driver, driver installations are restricted in our office systems. I have access to sqlplus to connect to database and have excel with vba scripting.

Comment: you can use ODBC database drivers if installed, the connectionstring is slightly different, odbc is slower then oleDb though, search for odbc in your startmenu
If not possible, try the solution with running sql files through Sql*Plus like I suggested in my a&nswer. No experience with vba, sorry